# Loop Through Magento Categories, Meta Keywords and Descriptions

Tags: php, magento, categories, meta

I have a file that is successfully looping through my categories and subcategories. I am successfully able to echo all the categories and their links

BUT

I do not understand why these (keywords and description) are not echoing

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($this->getKeywords()) ?>
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($this->getDescription()) ?>
```

The file is located here
app/design/frontend/mystoretheme/default/template/catalog/category/listofcats.phtml

Then im placing it on a block in a cms page {{block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.category" template="catalog/category/listofcats.phtml"}}

The goal is to be able to display each of the categories list of keywords and their descriptions within the same < li > and loop giving me a list like this

- Category
- Keywords
- Description

Here is my code. I have omitted my attempts at keyword and description since they are not working.

```
<div class="block block-list block-categories">
<div id="block-categories" class="block-title active">
    <strong><span>Categories </span></strong>
</div>  
<div id="leftnav" class="block-content" style="display:block">
    <?php $helper = $this->helper('catalog/category') ?>
        <?php $categories = $this->getStoreCategories() ?>
    <?php if (count($categories) > 0): ?>
        <ul id="leftnav-tree" class="level0">
            <?php foreach($categories as $category): ?>
                <li class="level0<?php if ($this->isCategoryActive($category)): ?> active<?php endif; ?>">
                    <a href="<?php echo $helper->getCategoryUrl($category) ?>"><span><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($category->getName()) ?></span></a>
                    <?php //if ($this->isCategoryActive($category)): ?>
                        <?php $subcategories = $category->getChildren() ?>
                        <?php if (count($subcategories) > 0): ?>
                            <ul id="leftnav-tree-<?php echo $category->getId() ?>" class="level1">
                                <?php foreach($subcategories as $subcategory): ?>
                                    <li class="level1<?php if ($this->isCategoryActive($subcategory)): ?> active<?php endif; ?>">
                                        <a href="<?php echo $helper->getCategoryUrl($subcategory) ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml(trim($subcategory->getName(), '- ')) ?></a>
                                         <?php $secondLevelSubcategories = $subcategory->getChildren() ?>
                                         <?php if (count($secondLevelSubcategories ) > 0): ?>
                            <ul id="leftnav-tree-<?php echo $subcategory->getId() ?>" class="level2">
                                <?php foreach($secondLevelSubcategories as $secondLevelSubcategory ): ?>
                                    <li class="level2<?php if ($this->isCategoryActive($secondLevelSubcategory )): ?> active<?php endif; ?>">
                                        <a href="<?php echo $helper->getCategoryUrl($secondLevelSubcategory ) ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml(trim($secondLevelSubcategory ->getName(), '- ')) ?></a>
                                    </li>
                                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                            </ul>
                            <script type="text/javascript">decorateList('leftnav-tree-<?php echo $category->getId() ?>', 'recursive')</script>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                            </ul>
                            <script type="text/javascript">decorateList('leftnav-tree-<?php echo $category->getId() ?>', 'recursive')</script>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php //endif; ?>
                </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
        <script type="text/javascript">decorateList('leftnav-tree', 'recursive')</script>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: what version of Magento are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this:

```
<?php
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
                ->getCollection()
                ->setStoreId(Put the store id here)
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addIsActiveFilter();
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    echo $category->getName();
    echo "-";
    echo $category->getMetaKeywords();
    echo "-";
    echo $category->getMetaDescription();
    echo "<br/>";
}
?>
```

Comment: That works great, however, I need to only display the store which i am displaying the page on not all stores categories. How would I modify that?

Comment: Just do this : ->setStoreId($storeId)  Please put the store id of the store you want.

Comment: Please see my modified answer above. If you liked it & working fine then please accept the answer + up-vote it. Thank you.

Comment: The store filter didn't work. It still displays all stores. I'm using magento EE 1.14.2 by the way.